# Generating hashCode from multiple fields?

Tags: java, hash, hashcode

How do I generate a hashCode from two fields in my class?

For example, I want `Pair` classes with the same objects V to have the same hashCode:

```
public class Pair<V> {
    V from, to;
}
```

Should I multiply their hashCodes together?  Add them?  Multiply them with a prime?

Comment: a look at how [lombok](http://projectlombok.org/features/EqualsAndHashCode.html) implements it might help

Comment: There are a **ton** of questions already on SO related to this. Was there something that wasn't clear?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

One way to do it is adding the hash code of the first field to hash code of the second field, multiplied by a small prime number, like this:

```
public int hashCode() {
    return 31 * from.hashCode() + to.hashCode();
}
```

Comment: Should there be parentheses here? Seems the explanation does not match the code.

Comment: No there is no parentheses

Comment: Why 31 and not an even smaller prime, such as 2?

Comment: @TrangOul There is no particular reason to use any specific prime. I would not pick 2, though, because it's the only even prime, so multiplying by it in the binary representation would amount to a simple shift. In other words, the result would be equivalent to `(from.hashCode() << 1) + to.hashCode()`. Although there is nothing particularly wrong with this approach, generally one would prefer more "mixing up" among the bits of the individual hash codes.